# Read byte data from a file into multiple integers

Tags: ruby, file, binary, integer

I'm trying to read data from a file containing continuous byte values for 4 byte integers. For example, the integers `1`, `2`, `3` would be stored in a file containing the bytes:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
```

I want to read this and assign each number to a different variable, for example `a = 1`, `b = 2`, and `c = 3`. How do I do this?

Any help will be appreciated with how to use the `read` and `unpack` commands. Also, if in the solution you give you can give a very brief explanation of why your code works.

This file is generated by a program written in Java. I am dumping bytes because speed is key, but if the process of reading into separate integers gets easier by adding a delimiter byte or something similar, I'd be open to that suggestion as well.

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [bindata](http://rubygems.org/gems/bindata) gem:

```
require 'bindata'

class MyBinaryFormat < BinData::Record
  uint32 :a
  uint32 :b
  uint32 :c
end

io = File.open('/path/to/binary/file')
result = MyBinaryFormat.read(io)

puts result.a  # 1
puts result.b  # 2
puts result.c  # 3
```

If you cannot use gems, you can use `String#unpack`. You will need to use the `N` format which stands for "Integer, 32-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order" (see [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-unpack)). By using `*` you tell Ruby to convert the bytes into the specified type until it runs out of data. Here's how you would use it:

```
io = File.open('/path/to/binary/file')
a, b, c = io.read(12).unpack('N*')  #=> 1, 2, 3
```

If you need to read more, adjust the parameter to `read` (here 3*4 = 12 bytes), accordingly.

Comment: Ah - I forgot to mention - I want to try to do this without using a gem. The reason is I need to use a proprietary Ruby API, and that does not support gems.

Comment: @PratikThaker see my edit on how to use the built-in method `unpack`.

Comment: Btw if you can run ruby code, you can run gems. Maybe it would be an option to vendor the gem into your project if you can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way not using `unpack`.

After you read this line into string(`str`):

```
arr = [] 
str = str.gsub(/\s/, '') #delete every space
len = str.length #get length of string
i = 0

while i<len #iterate over string until end(starting from 0)
    arr<<str[i...(i+16)].to_i(2) # "unpacking" 16 characters using range: 'string'[0...2] is 'st' & changing it into Integer with base 2(`to_i(base)`)
    i += 16 #going to next number(in your case 16 characters later)
end
```

When you store numbers in format like this "1 2 3", you your code should be faster because(as for my solution) you don't need to use `gsub` nor calculating where is number.
Nevertheless, I suggest you to benchmark codes you got from this topic. 
And if you are aiming for speed, you can try extend your code with C.

Here is ruby solution:

```
str = "1 2 3 4"
arr = str.split #split string on space (it's the same as `str.split(' ')` 
#result: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
numbers = arr.collect{|el| el.to_i} #for each string in `arr` it calls `to_i` and store result in new array(not `arr`)
#[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Of course, you can do one-liner like this:

```
numbers = str.split.collect &:to_i
```

or like this:

```
numbers = str.split.collect(|el| el.to_i}
```

Comment: I'm copying and pasting my reply to the post above: So these are using string operators? I wonder then, is it actually easier to just store these numbers as strings instead of byte values (so actually store "2" instead of 00000010)? Like I said, the file is created by a program I control so I can change it to output the number whatever format I wish. My only criteria is that it needs to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use special string operators to calculate a number from the binary. Your file contains the following:

```
00000000 00000001 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000011
```

And code looks like this:

```
# => ["00000000", "00000001", "00000000", "00000010", "00000000", "00000011"]
values =
IO.read( '1.1' ).split( /\s+/ ).map do| binary | # reading the file and splitting into an array by space
   i = -1
   binary.split( '' ).reverse.reduce( 0 ) do| sum, digit | # reduction binary into a digit
      i += 1
      sum + ( digit.to_i << i ) # sum by a digit
   end
end
=> [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

And for following code passes all values stroed previouly in the array into the function `proc_func` expanding the arguments:

```
def proc_func a, b, c, d, e, f
   puts a, b, c, d, e, f
end

proc_func *values

# 0
# 1
# 0
# 2
# 0
# 3
```

Comment: Hmm - that's interesting. So these are using string operators? I wonder then, is it actually easier to just store these numbers as strings instead of byte values (so actually store "2" instead of 00000010)? Like I said, the file is created by a program I control so I can change it to output the number whatever format I wish. My only criteria is that it needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: You should measure time for all proposed methods. But the main reason to use ruby is not speed, but usability, and simplicity to code. To make quick quick code the people use c, or for example, schema-like languages (see STALin).

Comment: Is it binary code? why shell you store "2" instead of 00000010?

Comment: So here is the actual problem: I am trying to create an application for a software (Google SketchUp) which has a Ruby API. Now I want to interface a controller (Leap Motion) that does not have a Ruby API attached to it. So what I am doing is taking the data the controller generates, outputting it to a file, and then reading it into SketchUp via Ruby. The issue is I'm generating a dataset every few milliseconds so it needs to flow efficiently between the two.

Comment: There are many ruby app written in c. Try our proposals, and if they dont satisfy you, you need to look at the article: http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/ProgrammingRuby/ext_ruby.html